# Jenkins CLI to install Jenkins plugins - error UnknownHostException

Tags: java, jenkins, command-line-interface, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I'm trying to use Jenkins CLI to install a Jenkins plugin with command:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 -auth @cred install-plugin https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/htmlpublisher/1.31/htmlpublisher.hpi
```

and got the error

```
Installing a plugin from https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/htmlpublisher/1.31/htmlpublisher.hpi

ERROR: Unexpected exception occurred while performing install-plugin command.
java.net.UnknownHostException: updates.jenkins.io
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:229)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:305)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
        at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:507)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:602)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:266)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:373)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:207)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:193)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1592)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
        at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1165)
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(FileUtils.java:1068)
        at hudson.cli.InstallPluginCommand.run(InstallPluginCommand.java:110)
        at hudson.cli.CLICommand.main(CLICommand.java:251)
        at hudson.cli.CLIAction$ServerSideImpl.run(CLIAction.java:299)
        at hudson.cli.CLIAction$1.lambda$opened$0(CLIAction.java:154)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

What I have tried out:

- Using another server:
  **java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 -auth @cred install-plugin https://get.jenkins.io/plugins/htmlpublisher/1.31/htmlpublisher.hpi** and got the same error
- Install a similar plugin from the Jenkins UI and this worked successfully.

Jenkins version: Jenkins 2.401.2

Appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This url is outdate: https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins and it migrate to the new url: https://get.jenkins.io/plugins

Please try the new url

Answer (score 0):

I found another workaround solution is using REST api to install specific Jenkins plugin version (downgrade/upgrade Jenkins plugin version)

```
curl -vu user:token -F "filename=plugin-name" -F "pluginUrl=https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/plugin-name/plugin-version/plugin-name.hpi" http://jenkins-url/manage/pluginManager/uploadPlugin
```

E.g:

```
curl -vu admin:11ba4f5453eed5ea3aa7d3c5307199e3e9 -F "filename=thinBackup" -F "pluginUrl=https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/thinBackup/1.15/thinBackup.hpi" http://localhost:8080/manage/pluginManager/uploadPlugin
```

Then restart Jenkins [image]

✨Tada!!! the result [image]

P/S: I want to use REST api instead of using GUI because with REST api we can write an automation script to install plugins versions list list as per requirement.